# XPath Expression -fails in Chrome But works in IE,FF

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, xpath, cross-browser

I am having an XML like this:

```
<root>
 <parent1>
   <parent2>
     <child label="single'quote"/>
     <child label="double&quot;quote"/>
   </parent2>
   <parent3/>
   <parent4>
     <child label = "single'quote"/>
   </parent4>
 </parent1>
</root>
```

My aim is to select the child node with a particular label,say **single'quote**

I can use the XPath Expression,

```
         //child[@label='single'quote']
```

which will obviously throw error because of the special character  ' in the value.

I came up with a solution to use the logic:

> set an attribute ***dummy*** to the parent node with the value of the label, and compare the two attributes. [Added **dummy="single'quote"** to **parent1** node.]

So, We can read the child nodes with the label as "single'quote" using:

```
 //child[@label=//parent1/@dummy]
```

Though it works perfectly fine in IE and Firefox9, it fails in Chrome21.

Is there any flaw with the logic? How can I correct the expression for Chrome?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why can't you just use `//child[@label="single'quote"]`? (or `//child[@label=&quot;single'quote&quot;]` if the xpath is in an attribute that uses ").

Comment: @DevNull In this case it fails, //child[@label="double&quot;quote"] :(

Comment: Right, but that XPath would change to `//child[@label='double&quot;quote']`. What am I missing?

Comment: I am using javascript to process the XML. So, I will be storingthe XPath as a string in a variable. So,It will be a single quote or double quote. How can it change ??

Like: evaluate("//child[@label=\""+labelVariable+"\"]",....,...)

Comment: @DevNull Sorry I did not see the edit. That expression fails. Its not returning the node with the value **double&quot;quote** :(

Comment: And I validated it here: http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/parent1/parent2/*[@label="single'quote"]
```

**Here is a screen-shot of the evaluation performed with the XPath Visualizer:**

[image]

**For the second question use**:

```
/*/parent1/parent2/*[@label='double"quote']
```

Here is  a screen-shot from the XPath Visualizer:

[image]

Comment: Yes that's right. Thank you :) But I am going to use the same string for both expressions just by simply replacing the value. Like: 

`var childvalue = "single'quote";
var expression = "/*/parent1/parent2/*[@label=\""+childvalue+"\"]";`

How can I fix it here. :(

Comment: @Sowmiya, This specific to the PL you are using -- not to XPath. Study your programming language for the ways you can produce that string. If you have problems, you can always debug your program.

Comment: Yep. Thanks a lot.:)

Btw, Any idea why that XPath Expression ` //child[@label=//parent1/@dummy]
` fails in Chrome browser alone?